# How to stream private media blob from azure blob storage without using a SAS url or sas token using shaka player

Tags: azure-storage, shaka

good day. Is it possible to access a private blob from azure storage without using a SAS url or SAS token to stream it on the shaka player? The shaka player keeps throwing error like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsr6X.png)

GET https://azure-url/ezdrm-test/dash_package_12072023_051840/h264_360p.mp4 401 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.)

I've already read, watch and tried the samples and documentation of azure but it was using only a SAS url or token. Is anybody have tried this one?

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to access a private blob from Azure storage without using a SAS URL or SAS token to stream it on the Shaka player?

No, It is not possible to access a private blob without a SAS URL or SAS token.

If you need to access private either you need an **`SAS token`** or **`Microsoft entra ID access token`**.

If you need to access the private blob with an access token, first you need to create one application in the portal.

After creating an application, you need to assign the **`Storage blob data contributor`** role to your application.

[image]

Using the above application, I created an **`access-token`** with the client credential flow through Postman.

**Postman:**

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/v2.0/token
    client_id:ClientID
    client_secret:ClientSecret
    scope:https://storage.azure.com/.default
    grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

Now, Using the above access token with x-ms-version in the header, I can able to fetch the video from Azure blob storage.

**Postman:**

```
GET https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net/demo/sample7.mp4
Headers:
 Authorization:Bearer <Access token>
 x-ms-version:2021-06-08
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Authorize access to blobs using Microsoft Entra ID - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory)

Comment: Yep, we've already done that. By the way, we encoded that media file using ezdrm, which it produces .mpd file. Now, we can create and load the sas url of the .mp4d file on our media player but when the player fetches the media of that .mpd file, that's when the access error occured.